# which mysqli functions do a client server round trip

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I want to understand how many client sever calls are made for a typical mysqli query?

```
Step(1) $result = mysqli_query($link, $query);
```

Depending on the type of query, we use other mysqli function after this like

```
mysqli_fetch_fields, mysqli_affected_rows, mysqli_insert_id, mysqli_fetch_row
```

etc. then we close the result object.

Now, is all data retrieved and stored in php memory after step (1)?
Or mysqli_fetch_fields, mysqli_insert_id etc makes another call to mysql server?

Reason for asking: Trying to understand how mysqli calls work. But can not find such explanation anywhere for beginners like me.

Answer (score 2):

PHP `MySQLi` API is built on MySQL C API. So it would be better if you have knowlegdes of it.

Basically, `SELECT` query could generate large ResultSet and this ResultSet is transfered from Server to Client when you call PHP's `mysqli_store_result()` (In C API, `mysql_store_result()`).

- C API `mysql_fetch_row()` just returns a pointer to MYSQL_RES* (which is already stored in PHP right after `mysql_store_result()`. But 'mysqli_fetch_row()` would require some memories to make PHP's array.
- `mysqli_insert_id()` (which is `last_insert_id()` of C API) just returns insert id of `MYSQL` connection data stucture which means there is no extra memory for insert id.

If you want to know how MySQLi works, I would recommand to learn MySQL C API and see PHP source codes.

Answer (score 1):

mysqli_query runs the query on the server and returns false is the query failed, true is the query was successful but did not return anything (UPDATE query for example) or a mysqli_result otherwise. That mysqli_result is a class that extends Traversable interface, so yes, it's in memory. All other functions mysqli_fetch_fields, mysqli_affected_rows etc. are just methods in that class so those just read what's already in memory.

For more details, read this: [php documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.mysqli-result.php)

Comment: Ok that is just I wanted to know. concise and to the point :)

Comment: A vote would be appreciated if you liked the response :)

Answer (score 1):

The [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/class.mysqli.php) tells you everything you need to know about `mysqli`.

`mysqli_query` execute the query and returns a [query object](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php), this object has some methods and amongst them there are:

- [`mysqli_fetch_fields`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-fields.php):

  > Returns an array of objects representing the fields in a result set
- [`mysqli_affected_rows`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.affected-rows.php):

  > Returns the number of rows affected by the last INSERT, UPDATE, REPLACE or DELETE query.
- [`mysqli_insert_id`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.insert-id.php):

  > Returns the auto generated id used in the last query
- [`mysqli_fetch_row`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-row.php):

  > Get a result row as an enumerated array

Being all method of an object they don't execute sql requests, they simply access object values and gives you back different results depending on the method.

Comment: I knew that these are methods of mysqli object, just wanted to clarify if these methods do a server roundtrip internally to fetch that information. Not my confusion is cleared :)